# Unable to install Cuda in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: command-line, nvidia, graphics, cuda

```
(base) edith@edith:~$ sudo apt-get install cuda
[sudo] password for edith: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-20 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-18 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-10 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-8 but it is not installable or
                                          xorg-video-abi-6.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you installed the driver already? And did you add a ppa?

Comment: Yes i have installed